# Groupby column name and add results as additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'stuff_1_var_1': range(5),
    'stuff_1_var_2': range(2, 7),
    'stuff_2_var_1': range(3, 8),
    'stuff_2_var_2': range(5, 10)
})

   stuff_1_var_1  stuff_1_var_2  stuff_2_var_1  stuff_2_var_2
0              0              2              3              5
1              1              3              4              6
```

I would like to `groupby` based on the column headers and then add the `mean` and `median` of each group as new columns. So my expected output looks like this:

```
   stuff_1_var_mean  stuff_1_var_median  stuff_2_var_mean  stuff_2_var_median
0                 1                   1                 4                   4
1                 2                   2                 5                   5
```

Brief explanation:
we have two groups `stuff_1_var_` and `stuff_2_var_` for which would calculate the mean and median per row. So, e.g. for `stuff_1_var_` it would be:

```
# values from stuff_1_var_1 and stuff_1_var_2
(0 + 2) / 2 = 1 and 
( 1 + 3) / 2 = 2
```

The values are then added as a new column `stuff_1_var_mean`; analogue for `meadian` and `stuff_2_var_`.

I got until:

```
df = df.T

pattern = df.index.str.extract('(^stuff_\d_var_)', expand=False)

dfgb = df.groupby(pattern).agg(['mean', 'median']).T

          stuff_1_var_  stuff_2_var_
0 mean               1             4
  median             1             4
1 mean               2             5
  median             2             5
```

How can I do the final step(s)?

Comment: how would the output dataframe look like? the mean/median value will be duplicated across rows?

Comment: Your expected output is...confusing. Please clarify.

Comment: @YOLO: The desired output is included in the question; I added a bit more explanation; hope it is clearer now?!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander: I added a bit more explanation; hope it is clearer now?!

Comment: OK, give me some time.

Comment: You should learn about [tidy data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data). It's always much easier to do computation when your data is in tidy format. Here the reason why your data is not tidy is that there are variables "var_*X*" "stuff_*Y*"  in your column name.

Comment: @godot: Thanks for the link! I am only on the receiving end here, so I don't have influence on the input format, unfortunately.

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't change it before proceeding... It can seem a lot of work at first but it's a really rewarding in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be changed:

```
df = df.T

pattern = df.index.str.extract('(^stuff_\d_var_)', expand=False)

dfgb = df.groupby(pattern).agg(['mean', 'median']).T.unstack()
dfgb.columns = dfgb.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')

print (dfgb)
   stuff_1_var_mean  stuff_1_var_median  stuff_2_var_mean  stuff_2_var_median
0                 1                   1                 4                   4
1                 2                   2                 5                   5
2                 3                   3                 6                   6
3                 4                   4                 7                   7
4                 5                   5                 8                   8
```

Unfortunately for `axis=1` is not implemented `agg`, so possible solution is create `mean` and `median` separately and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfgb = df.groupby(pattern, axis=1).agg(['mean','median'])
```

> NotImplementedError: axis other than 0 is not supported

```
pattern = df.columns.str.extract('(^stuff_\d_var_)', expand=False)
g = df.groupby(pattern, axis=1)

dfgb = pd.concat([g.mean().add_suffix('mean'), 
                  g.median().add_suffix('median')], axis=1)
dfgb = dfgb.iloc[:, [0,2,1,3]]
print (dfgb)
   stuff_1_var_mean  stuff_1_var_median  stuff_2_var_mean  stuff_2_var_median
0                 1                   1                 4                   4
1                 2                   2                 5                   5
2                 3                   3                 6                   6
3                 4                   4                 7                   7
4                 5                   5                 8                   8
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks again! Will wait with acceptance for a bit to check whether anything else shows up.

Comment: @Cleb - Is order of columns important?

Comment: @Cleb - Is possible first all means and then all median columns?

Comment: The order of columns is not important, no.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do:

```
col = 'stuff_1_var_'
use_col = [x for x in df.columns if 'stuff_1' in x]

df[f'{col}mean'] = df[use_col].mean(1)
df[f'{col}median'] = df[use_col].median(1)

col2 = 'stuff_2_var_'
use_col = [x for x in df.columns if 'stuff_2' in x]

df[f'{col2}mean'] = df[use_col].mean(1)
df[f'{col2}median'] = df[use_col].median(1)

print(df.iloc[:,-4:]) # showing last four new columns

  stuff_1_var_mean  stuff_1_var_median  stuff_2_var_mean  stuff_2_var_median  
0               1.0                 1.0               4.0                 4.0  
1               2.0                 2.0               5.0                 5.0  
2               3.0                 3.0               6.0                 6.0  
3               4.0                 4.0               7.0                 7.0  
4               5.0                 5.0               8.0                 8.0
```

Ofcourse, you can put it in a function to avoid repeating the same code.

Comment: Not as straightforward as @jezrael's answer, but still worth an upvote :)